# Msmq disaster recovery

Tags: msmq, disaster-recovery

I trying to use  synchronisation  tool (double take) to synchronize the  MSMQ storage folder  **"C:\Windows\System32\msmq\storage"** 
from one server to another one
The problem that once the files moved to the second server, the Message queue service couldn’t be started
I found that if I exclude the *.MQ files the synchronization work fine but in this case I will be losing the transactional messages 
Anybody have a solution to keep the transactinal messages ?

Thank you

Comment: actually it work fine after i make both computers same name

Answer (score 1):

MSMQ uses multiple files in the storage directory for transactional messages. Any attempt to copy the storage directory while MSMQ is working on transactional messages is likely to result in files that are not in synch with each other. Only guaranteed way to do this is to stop the MSMQ service first. This is how MQBKUP.EXE works, for example.

Cheers
John

Comment: so I think the only way to have disaster recovery for MSMQ is the microsoft clustering 2008,right?

Comment: That is the supported approach, yes. An alternative (which I've seen in practice) can be to have a fault-tolerant design, such as sending the same message to multiple servers with some extra processing to delete the unused duplicates.